# Call to GetRequestStream works in ASP.Net but not for console application

Tags: asp.net, .net, api, console, webrequest

I have some code in an ASP.Net class that I've used on my web based application for over two years now.  I'm looking to perform some similar business function in a command line tool.  I'm using identical code in both applications, but the command line application is timing out at the call to "GetRequestStream" near the bottom of the code.

I've been able to get the call to GetRequestStream to work if I close req and req2 when I'm done with them.  However, in order for req3 to authenticate, it needs req and req2 to remain open.  So, if I leave req and req2 open, GetRequestStream times out.  If I close req and req2, then the call to GetRequestStream works, but req3 fails to authenticate.

As I mentioned, the exact same code is working fine as a web based, ASP.Net application.  It's only when I use this class building it as a console based application, do I run into these problems.

I'm thinking that this must be something with connections, but I'm fairly new to building command line apps from .Net.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
            string uri = baseUri + "auth/authrequired";
            HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
            req.Timeout = 1000000;
            req.Proxy = null;
            req.CookieContainer = cc;
            var MyWebResponse = (WebResponse)req.GetResponse();

            uri = baseUri + "authenticated/identity";
            HttpWebRequest req2 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
            req2.Timeout = 1000000;
            req2.Proxy = null;
            req2.CookieContainer = cc;
            MyWebResponse = req2.GetResponse();

            uri = baseUri + "j_security_check";
            string reqParams = "j_username=" + "jmclaughlin" + "&j_password=" + "jmclaughlin";  
            byte[] reqData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(reqParams);

            HttpWebRequest req3 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
            req3.Timeout = 1000000;
            req3.Proxy = null;
            req3.CookieContainer = cc;
            req3.Method = "POST";
            req3.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            req3.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
            req3.ContentLength = reqData.Length;
            using (var s = req3.GetRequestStream())
                s.Write(reqData, 0, reqData.Length);
            MyWebResponse = req3.GetResponse();
```

Answer (score 3):

You're calling `GetResponse`, but never disposing of it. That's keeping the connection alive until the response is finalized. Basically, you should be using a `using` statement for the response:

```
using (var response = req.GetResponse())
{
    // Do whatever with the response
}
```

Because you're never releasing the connection, when you've used up the limit of concurrent connections to any one host, you're basically waiting for the old connections to be released. If you dispose of your responses properly, that won't be a problem.

It's probably only working in ASP.NET because other work is causing garbage collection (and therefore finalization) - but it would still be better to dispose of the responses in a timely manner.

Comment: Thanks Jon.  I figured it was something that garbage collection was handling for me.  That worked fine!